# How to set the text of a TextView?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to learn about Xamarin Android and I have some dubts.

I have a layoout, my .xaml file and my .cs file (I am not sure if this could be considerate my view model in the same way than in the WPF applications).

In my layout I have this:

```
<TextView
    android:text="txtDireccionServicio"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtDireccionServicio" />
```

but in the text I have a warning that tell me that is is a hardcode value, that I should to use a @string resource.

Well, I have in my .cs file this property:

```
private string txtDireccionServicio = "Prueba";
```

But I don't know how to use this propery in my layout. I have tried this:

```
android:text="@txtDireccionServicio"
```

But it shows "@txtDireccionServicio". But in this case the layout doesn't warn that it is a hardcode value.

So my question is, how could I bind the Text property of the TextView with the string property in my .cs file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't support **Data-Binding** in default . So we need to set the text by using `Element.Property=xxx`

**In your activity**

```
TextView tx = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtDireccionServicio);
tx.Text = "xxx";
```

**Note:**

We need to invoke the line `tx.Text = "xxx";` if we change the value of text in runtime .